# How to migrate SharedPreferences during update?

Tags: android, updates, android-preferences, migrate

I would like to change a SharedPreference from Boolean to String. The default value was true and will be "enabled". This is not a problem because it will be set automatically. But how can I check if it was set to false and then set the new preferece to "disabled"? Is there a method called during update of the app where I could migrate this preference?
If I don't migrate it, the state of this preference is lost during update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a simple method in the first activity which'll open, to update the preferences values for you. Also, add a check so that it executes only for the first time.

Comment: There is no method called after an app Update? Running the code every time seems not so elegant to me....

Comment: No, I don't think there's a method which is called specifically after an update. But you could run your code to update the sharedPrefs only if the key exists (i.e the first time your app runs after update) and then remove that key after adding the new String Pref. Every subsequent time, since the key doesnt exist, the code for updation won't run.

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = // obtain it
String pref;
try {
    pref = preferences.getString("yourPref", "enabled");
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // this means the pref is stored as a boolean
    boolean boolPref = preferences.getBoolean("yourPref", true);
    // store it instead as a String
    pref = boolPref ? "enabled" : "disabled";
    preferences.edit().remove("yourPref").putString("yourPref", pref).commit();
}
```